# How to fix sculpting ridges?

Tags: sculpting

I ran into a problem I have never seen before and that is when I try to sculpt on a mesh, it sculpts like this:[image]

Instead of this:[image]
I am using dyntopo with these settings:[image]
[image]

I feel like theres a very obvious solution to this, but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must apply scale first. Select the object in object mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> *Scale*

See also [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)